# Form validation for relational elements

Tags: cakephp

I have a form in CakePHP to save information to multiple models.
My first model is "World", I have no problem for these fields the validation is correct and it's saved correctly to the database.
The second model is "Country", I use something like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Country.0.name');
```

This is correctly saved to the database, but there is no validation (like stairs for required fields) and no automagic (autodetection of the content type).
The third model is "Region", I use the same code as for the second one but there is no validation, no automagic and no saving...

Can someone help ?

Thank you,
Sébastien

Comment: I want to do the exact same thing, did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, I am guessing that you are trying to save multiple countries at the same time. The model expects the data to come in a specific format:

```
$this->data['Model']['field'];
```

What you are passing is:

```
$this->data['Model'][0]['field'];
```

The model cannot interpret it. The way to resolve this is build a foreach when you collect the data and send each request independently.

```
foreach($country as $field) {
   $data['Country']['field'] = $field;
   // add other fields that are required

   if($this->Country->validates($data)) {
      $this->Country->create();
      $this->Country->save($data);
   } else {
      // error handling
   }
}
```

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Actualy, `$this->data['Model'][0]['field'];` is the format awaited by Cake when you want to save related model data with hasMany relation : [link](http://book.cakephp.org/view/84/Saving-Related-Model-Data-hasOne-hasMany-belongsTo).

Comment: What I want is something like that :
`echo $this->Form->input('World.name');
echo $this->Form->input('Country.0.name');
echo $this->Form->input('City.0.name');`
Where I use `$this->World->saveAll($this->data);` in the controller to save a new World, a new related country and a new related city for the new country in one shot.